# Reading Json returned by MongoDB in PHP

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I got a task to get to find out ER from json files  this is the one record

```
{ "__v" : 0, "_id" : ObjectId( "52210bf6880b9f0200000003" ), "email" : "", "emailFrequency" : "instant", "feedbackRating" : 0, "field_aboutMe" : "On Fridays I like to eat apples.", "field_contact" : "me@matt.is", "field_intro" : "Sparkboard bug-fixer. Co-founded Hacking Health, Bodo Wellness, and BrainTripping.", "first_time" : false, "hash" : "", "name" : "Matt Huebert", "picture" : "https://www.ssss.com", "ready" : true, "roles" : [ "admin" ], "email" : "", "tags" : [ "Developer", "Designer", "Mentor" ], "updatedAt" : Date( 1384115378947 ), "votesByDomain" : { "sadsard-com" : "525eadf50f13910200000004" } }
```

after searching i found out it has something to do with MongoDB . I need to parse this data to find out Entities in it . when i check its validation its not a valid json as its been generated by mongo db  .
Please any body have any idea  ?

Ive tried this as well

```
$data = file_get_contents('json/users.json');
bson_decode($data);
```

tried json_decode as well its also not working and returning NULL

I get this error while trying to bson_decode

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'type 0x5f not supported

Comment: Should be `json_decode`. It's a typo.

Comment: jsond_decode is not working and returning null ....as this is not a normal json file i tried that as well

Comment: This isn't JSON, but BSON so json_decode is never going to work.

Comment: tried bson_decode as well

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what has dumped this into your json file, possibly from stdout of mongo shell,  But this part is the problem:

```
ObjectId( "52210bf6880b9f0200000003" )
```

You need to remove the Wrapping "ObjectId(" and closing brace ")" in order to make each line valid JSON. Once that is filtered you are left with valid JSON.

If you know who is providing you with these files, and cannot use the mongodb datasource directly, then ask them to please use [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/), which will at least give you valid JSON from the start.

Comment: Same thing for the Date("").. This isn't valid JSON. This looks like "extended json" the MongoDB shell uses. Mixing Extended JSON, JSON and BSON here all in one go is... confusing :) - Use mongoexport into json and use json_decode() like Neil is suggesting would make things a lot simpler